# Encrypting exception: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm trying to decrypt with my own key the following string:

"zW4%3D1p1%2AjR9E"

```
private static void init(String password) throws Exception {
    PBEKeySpec PBEKeySpecification = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
    keyDES = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encrypted_algorithm).generateSecret(PBEKeySpecification);
    myCipher = Cipher.getInstance(encrypted_algorithm);
    algorithmSpecification = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCounter);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "zW4%3D1p1%2AjR9E";
    String infoDesencriptada = null;
    try {
        init("abc123ab");
        myCipher.init(2, keyDES, algorithmSpecification);
        BASE64Decoder base64Enc = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] arrayBase64Enc = base64Enc.decodeBuffer(input);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = myCipher.doFinal(arrayBase64Enc);
        infoDesencriptada = new String(decryptedBytes, "UTF8");
    } catch (Exception var5) {
        System.out.println("Some exception:" + var5.getMessage());
        var5.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error: **javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded**

Any help?

Comment: Did you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110062/java-decryption-input-length-must-be-multiple-of-8-when-decrypting-with-padded ?

Comment: Well, have you checked if the input data is a multiple of 8?  Use your debugger.  Also, what is the value of `encrypted_algorithm`?

Comment: Check my edit please.

Comment: Once again, what is the value of `encrypted_algorithm`?

Comment: Is necessary to know the encrypted_algorithm value? @LukePark

Comment: Uhhhh... don't worry about it then.

Comment: 1. Generally a bad padding error just means the decryption failed, the wrong key, to IV, incorrect encoding of the key, IV or data. 2. The input ("zW4%3D1p1%2AjR9E7" is 17 character) is not a multiple of the block size, 8-bytes for DES. 3. Using DES in new work should not be dome, it is no longer secure.

Answer (score 1):

In the question text the data is `"zW4%3D1p1%2AjR9E"` but in the code it is `"zW4%3D1p1%2AjR9E7"`, note the extra trailing `7`.

The input must be a multiple of the block size, 8-bytes for DES so it seems there is a simple entry error in the code.